# Layout with multiple images on Facebook open graph object

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api, layout

In Facebook object graph, is there any possibility to change the published object layout to display more than one image?

In the open graph object data it is possible to include more than one image, which lets the users select upon publishing the image they would like to publish. But what if I want to change the object layout to display two images at the same post? Is it possible?

Comment: I don’t think it is. You’d have to combine the two images the user chooses into one image server-side, and then have this composite image set as _the_ image for the OG object, I’d say.

Comment: Yes, that was my next option. Thank you CBroe.